# Is it possible to make the HERE maps copyright logo appear on NMAMapViews with less than 230pt height?

Tags: ios, here-api

It appears the iOS HERE maps SDK automatically removes the HERE maps copyright logo when using an `NMAMapView` with width of 266pt and a height smaller than 230pt. Is there a way to force it to appear?

If not, can someone point me to the documentation for this so that I can show our legal team who are asking for the copyright logo to always be shown.

Answer (score 0):

230px is the minimum set in the SDK. Smaller values and the HERE logo does not fit properly. This is as per the HERE brand guidelines.

Please contact HERE tech support to see if this requirement can be voided for this specific case and if there is an alternate attribution method.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for getting back to me. Could you please post a link to the brand guidelines as I'm struggling to find it.

Comment: HI, please contact HERE technical support for your case :)